# How do you add CH to EAX in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I need to add the contents of `CH` to `EAX` in x86 assembly, but there is no address mode that appears to support this. Ideally I would want an addressing mode like:

```
ADD EAX,r8
```

or

```
ADD r32,r8
```

or

```
ADD r/m32,r8
```

But `ADD` does not have any of these modes. I can't mask `ECX` because it has other junk in it that I use elsewhere, and I have used up all my other registers, so my only option appears to be to use a memory access. Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Note I can't use a mode like `r/m8,r8` because then there will be no carry.

Comment: It's time to go for x64 and get those extra registers. :)

Comment: [Omitting frame pointer](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) helps you freeing one more register, makes function calls faster and produce smaller code with the trade for more difficult debugging. But anyway, going 64-bit is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86 just doesn't have such flexible addressing modes, as you've observed. You can't add an 8-bit register to a 32-bit register in a single step. Your options are either to free up a register and zero/sign extend then add r32,r32, or to add r8,r8 then branch on the carry flag to adjust the result.

I'd suggest you should spill a register to memory, on a modern processor a pair of memory accesses are much cheaper than a branch (as it will load from the store buffer), and you can probably reword your other code around the spill.

Answer (score 2):

Use a mode like r/m8,r8 and propagate the carry if necessary by adding a constant 0x100 to EAX.

Answer (score 2):

If you spill a register, you could avoid branching. e.g.,

```
subl $4, %esp
```

use the instruction sequence:

```
movl %eax, (%esp)
...
movzbl %ch, %eax
...
addl (%esp), %eax
```

and restore the stack pointer at the end:

```
addl $4, %esp
```

It might play havoc with any attempts to debug the code within this block, if that's an issue.

---

Or, following Doug Currie's suggestion:

```
addb %ch, %al
jnc  done
addl 0x100, %eax
done:
```

Comment: Isn't the above code the same as "push eax"  (followed by "pop eax" at the end)?

Comment: Yes - but I don't know if this is required in a loop or not, so I thought I'd make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing Doug's answer (in Intel syntax):

```
  add al, ch
  jnc no_carry
  add eax, 100h
no_carry:
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, for eax:

```
add al,ch
adc ah,0
rorx eax,16
adc ax,0
rorx eax,16
```

In the first instruction you add lower part and preserve carry flag, in the second instruction you add the carry flag to the higher part of the register. It also preserves the content of the source. Beware of the registers stalls though and mix the code with other instructions to avoid it.

Added:

```
add al,ch
adc ah,0
bswap eax
xchg al,ah
adc ax
xchg al,ah
bswap eax
```

Comment: works for haspwell only though (macro for short rotate without carry version, takes 1 cycle) ...
other options are bswap, xchg

Comment: indirect jumps may have greater penalty than greater amount of instructions, so it makes sense to use more instructions

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the 32-bit values and undo the adding of the 24 msb:s:

```
 add eax, ecx
 xor cl,cl           // also `and ecx, 0xffffff00` is possible
 sub eax, ecx
```

This naturally destroys the value to be added, but preserves the junk.
(And re-reading the question, there's actually need to surround the code block with `xchg cl,ch`, which makes the solution suboptimal to the task.)